# AWS Media Convert output to S3 - Can i have NO subfolders

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

I have a workflow based on https://github.com/aws-solutions/video-on-demand-on-aws-foundation where i upload a MP4 file to a bucket, it gets converted and put into a folder structure that looks like this `<guid>/<OutputGroups/CustomName>/file.xxx`.  If i remove the CustomName from the job-settings.json file then its `<guid>/AppleHLS1/file.xxx` or `<guid>/FileGroup1/file.xxx`.

What i want is all the file group files placed directly in the GUID folder and NOT create a folder under the GUID. Is there a way to override Media Convert wanting to create these sub-folders? I have searched high and low for an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

The output path including subdirectories is set in each Output Group under the   File Group Settings/Destination  or in the JSON at:

"OutputGroupSettings": {
"Type": "FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS",
"FileGroupSettings": {
"Destination": "s3://bucketname"

FileGroupSettings is independent of CustomName or NameModifier settings.
Try adjusting FileGroupSettings  and see if that solves your issue.